# Javascript convert between timezones with momentjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, datetime, timezone, momentjs

in my app the user selects a date + time, and a timezone. This choice must be shown to other users IN THEIR OWN timezone, which means if user A from New York chooses August 8, 3:00 AM in EDT, user B from Beijing will see this datetime converted to China Standard Time (CST).

To do this I thought - ok I save user A's date and tell him to select out of 4 timezones. Server side I convert this from his EDT choice to UTC using moment timezone, and save it as UTC in the database, so that when I read it, I convert it back to other users according to their own timezones.

Is this a correct approach or am I overcomplicating things? THe purpose is that user A can choose her desired timezone, database saves as normalized UTC, target user sees in his own timezone.

(im using node.js for serverside btw)
Thanks,

Comment: What's "normalized UTC"? You'll have to store the timezone, don't you? Like `"CST"` or `-6`.

Comment: Your approach is absolutely correct.

Comment: @Rudie - yes, correct; i figured i store the date as UTC, and a separate field iwth timezone "CST".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your approach is correct : save the time in UTC in the database and display it to the users according to their timezones.

`momentjs` can help you to do it but you need to give it the file of historical timezone changes.

check http://momentjs.com/timezone/ for further explanations.

once you have this, it is as easy as

```
var jun = moment("2014-06-01T12:00:00Z");
jun.tz('America/Los_Angeles').format('ha z');  // 5am PDT
```

also: don't store the user timezone as EDT, CST or -6. The hour shift can change with Summer times, Winter times, .. you need to store the Olson format, 'America/Los_Angeles'

Comment: Actually, you don't need much help displaying the UTC date/time in the user's timezone. As long as you are happy with displaying it using the timezone set of the user's machine, that's pretty much how things work by default. For instance, "new Date('2014-08-24 14:52:31Z')' when printed using `toString` on a machine in India yields "Sun Aug 24 2014 20:22:31 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)".

Comment: @Jerome WAGNER - thank you for your reply; regarding your last comment, I figured out I would do this: store "KST", and on client: if(KST)then moment.tz(utcDate, 'Asia/Seoul') - would this be ok?

Comment: @Amc_rtty no I would not store 'KST' because KST is usually understood wrt a specific point in time (sometimes you have KDT). By using a geographic mapping (Asia/Seoul) you store something that is not linked with a specific point in time (except when it refers to the place where the user was when the time was stored).