# Convert date from one timezone to another in momentjs

Tags: javascript, momentjs, moment-timezone

I have one datetime e.g. 22 Nov 2020, 04:59 in (GMT+10:00) Australia/ACT (Eastern Standard Time (New South Wales)) now I want to get equivalent date for this time in (GMT+3:00) Asia/Kuwait (Arabia Standard Time). I am using moment js . Please suggest

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript convert between timezones with momentjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25470057/javascript-convert-between-timezones-with-momentjs)

Comment: See also [Moment Timezone | Docs | Converting to Zone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/converting-to-zone/). Does that help you at all?

Answer (score 1):

We can parse your ACT time using the [moment.tz](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/parsing-in-zone/) constructor, we can then clone and convert to the Kuwait timezone.

```js
const actTime = moment.tz("22 Nov 2020, 04:59", "DD MMM YYYY, HH:mm", "Australia/ACT");
const kuwaitTime = actTime.clone().tz("Asia/Kuwait");

console.log("Moment.js:");
console.log("ACT Time:", actTime.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm"));
console.log("Kuwait Time:", kuwaitTime.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.25/moment-timezone-with-data-10-year-range.js"></script>
```

We could also do the same thing using the rather awesome new [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/index.html) module (Luxon can be thought of as the evolution of Moment. It is authored by Isaac Cambron, a long-time contributor to Moment.)

```js
const { DateTime } = luxon;

const actTime = DateTime.fromFormat("22 Nov 2020, 04:59", "dd MMM yyyy, HH:mm", { zone: "Australia/ACT"});
const kuwaitTime = actTime.setZone("Asia/Kuwait")

console.log("Luxon:");
console.log("ACT Time:", actTime.toFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"));
console.log("Kuwait Time:", kuwaitTime.toFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/luxon/1.25.0/luxon.min.js" integrity="sha512-OyrI249ZRX2hY/1CAD+edQR90flhuXqYqjNYFJAiflsKsMxpUYg5kbDDAVA8Vp0HMlPG/aAl1tFASi1h4eRoQw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```